# Hard Disk Space Needed For Website

Tags: php, html, iframe, youtube, hosting

I have a very simple website, literally it is just an iFrame which streams a YouTube video. However, you can pass video IDs to it via url parameters using php. Now, I only have about 150MB of HDD space (forgive me if this is not relevant! I know nothing about html or web hosting).

OK so if 100 users are using my site, all watching different YouTube videos, will I run out of space? Will there be some kind of issue? Or will 100 users be able to watch different videos through this iFrame at the same time?

Comment: Disk space is irrelevant if YouTube hosts all of the content other than a single PHP file.

Comment: If videos are in youtube, don't worry about hard disk.

Comment: wow, 1 minute to get an answer. I am impressed!

Answer (score 1):

No, you won't.

You only have to store your website on your hard disk, probably not more than a few PHP files depending on your website. You will be more than fine with 150mb of storage.

The streamed videos will be downloaded directly from the YouTube servers to your visitors' computers. They will never be stored on your server.